# Deleting an event from iPhone's calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to delete an event from the Calendar on user request. This is what I've come up with:

```
// Deleting Event
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = appDelegate.title1;
event.startDate = appDelegate.recAddDate;
event.endDate   = appDelegate.currentDateName;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Below is the function I'm calling to remove the event from the event array. Items array is used to fetch events from iPhone calendar

```
- (BOOL)removeEvent:(EKEvent *)event span:(EKSpan)span error:(NSError **)error{
    VoiceRecorderAppDelegate *appDelegate = (VoiceRecorderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:appDelegate.objectindexpath];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482920/removing-events-from-iphone-calendar-with-ekeventstore

Comment: There are two duplicate answers !!!

Answer (score 16):

Firstly, save the eventId for the event while adding/saving events to the calendar.

```
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
[arrayofEventId addObject:str];
```

and then identify the event you want to remove ande then remove that event.

```
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:[arrayofEventId objectAtIndex:i]];
 if (eventToRemove != nil) {  
   NSError* error = nil;
  [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
 }
```

Also don't forget to remove that event from arrayofEventId as well.

Comment: can u tel me what is 'arrayofEventId', where u declared it.

Comment: Looks like it's just an empty NSMutableArray, you can declare it yourself. with [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: i just NSLog(%@",event.eventIdentifier) and it give null can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in the following ways:

> By creating an `NSpredicate` using the date range withing which you
>   want to delete events, 86400 being the duration of a day in events, in
>   this piece of code I am deleting month old events. I am using a
>   dispatch queue, as the no. of events fetched may be large, and to keep the UI free.

First Create the event store and check access(access check required only iOS6 onwards):

```
    - (void)addEventsToCalendar {
        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
            //implementation for devices running OS version iOS 6.0 onwards.
            [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                if (granted) {
                    [self removeEventsFromStore:eventStore];
                } else {
                    //perform for No Access using Error
            }];
        } else {
            //implementation for devices running OS version lower than iOS 6.0.
            [self removeEventsFromStore:eventStore];
        }
    }
```

Then remove events from the store:

```
    - (void)removeEventsFromStore:(EKEventStore*)eventStore {
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-30 * 86400];
        NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.arc.calendar", NULL);

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[PWCCalendar getCalendarForEventStore:eventStore]];
            NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:ONE_DAY_DURATION sinceDate:endDate] calendars:calendarArray];
            NSArray *eventArray = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
            for (EKEvent *event in eventArray) {
                [eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:NULL];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Get the main Queue and perform UPdates
            });
        });
    }
```

This is the Long way, use it to delete events in bulk. But if you need to delete only One event, then save the events identifier to `NSUserDefaults(after generating the event)

```
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:NULL];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[event eventIdentifier] forKey:@"Event ID"];
```

and then fetch it back while removing using

```
[eventStore eventWithIdentifier:@"Event ID"];
```

and then remove it from the store using

```
[eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:NULL];
```

For more clarifications on the other methods to fetch events or calendar, pelase refer to `EventStore docs:` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567 or to the `Calendar and Reminder Programming guide:` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765