# EKEvent - Change Status of event

Tags: ios, objective-c, icalendar, status, ekevent

I was developing a calendar app where we can see all the events from iCal. In app, we have option to cancel the event. If the event is cancelled then we need to change the status of event. But status property of EKEvent is read only so we can't change the status when the event is cancelled.

Can anyone suggest me how to proceed this problem? Is there any way to change the status of event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to remove EKEvnet from Calendar. check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482920/removing-events-from-iphone-calendar-with-ekeventstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read description of `EKEvent` (in EKEvent standard framework ) there is they mention

> @discussion While the status offers four different values in the
>   EKEventStatus enumeration,
>                   in practice, the only actionable and reliable status is canceled. Any other status
>                   should be considered informational at best. You cannot set this property. If you
>                   wish to cancel an event, you should simply remove it using removeEvent:.

so you have to delete that event if you want to cancel

Comment: Hello Jay. Please attach reference URL to the documentation you cited here. :)

Comment: Thanks Jay. Let me do this way.

Comment: @ NSNoob i have copied it from EKEvent framework from Xcode so can not give reference URL for that